# Laravel - User edit form not linking to controller

Tags: laravel

UPDATE: I think the issue is definitely with the form method POST. I've reworded my question and given full code in a new thread here  [stackoverflow.com/questions/58043675/form-method-post-action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043675/form-method-post-action)

I'm creating a page for users to update their settings (settings.blade.php), it's stored inside a user_admin folder, so the correct path is `user_admin/settings.blade.php.`

Here is my SettingsController.php

```
public function edit()

{
 $user = auth()->user();
return view('user_admin.settings', compact('user'));
}
```

And here is how I am trying to link to it;

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('user_admin/settings.edit', $settings->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
```

The error I get is

> 'Undefined variable'

I've also tried `{{ route('settings') }}`, but I get error:

> 'Route [settings] not defined.'

Here the form input in my form that users edit:

```
 <label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>
```

Plus, in the user dashboard, I have a link to 'settings' which is 
`{{ route('user_admin/settings.edit')}}`. The trouble, the dashboard won't open because of the error

> Route [user_admin/settings.edit] not defined

Here are my Routes:

```
Route::get('settings', 'SettingsController@edit');
Route::post('settings/update', 'SettingsController@update');
```

END

Everything below this line is my reply to specific comments.

@Rashed Hasan

```
|        | POST      | password/email             | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest                                       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset             | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest                                       |
|        | POST      | password/reset             | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest                                       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}     | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest                                       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | pricing                    |                  | Closure                                                                | web                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                   | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest                                       |
|        | POST      | register                   |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest                                       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | settings                   |                  | App\Http\Controllers\SettingsController@edit                           | web                                             |
|        | POST      | settings/update            |                  | App\Http\Controllers\SettingsController@update                         | web                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | uli_groups_created         |                  | Closure                                                                | web                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | uli_groups_joined          |                  | Closure                                                                | web                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | upload_profile_image       |                  | Closure                                                                | web                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | welcome                    |                  | Closure                                                                | web                                             |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You are passing `user` variable to your `blade file` and in form `url` you're writing `$settings->id`. from where you find the `$settings` ??

Comment: Are you refering to this {{ route('user_admin/settings.edit')}}? This is because the settings.blade.php file is inside a folder called user_admin

Comment: `route` is not related to the folder. Please run `php artisan route:list` in terminal. In the list you will find your `route`.

Comment: I have run ```php artisan route:list``` and posted result above.

Comment: Already some persons corrected your code. Now, your problem is solved or not?

Comment: @Rashed Hasan Yes, thank you for suggesting to run route:list. The problem was caused due to a previous change to user name, we added user first_name and last_name to sign up form, which meant that 'name' was not being recognised. Thanks for your help! And, this is the correct link {{ route('settings.update') }}

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should give name to each and every route like,

```php
Route::get('settings', 'SettingsController@edit')->name('settings');
Route::post('settings/update', 'SettingsController@update')->name('settings_update');
```

This way you can uniquely identify each and every route

Now what you did in below code:

```html
<form
  method="POST"
  action="{{ route('user_admin/settings.edit', $settings->id)}}"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
```

You have passed an ID with the route but there is not any route defined with parameter, refer below code: Route:

```php
Route::get('user/{id}/profile','ProfileController@profile')->name('profile');
```

Inside blade file:

```xml
<form 
  method="POST" 
  action="{{route('profile', ['id' => 1])}}"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
```

So basically in `route()` function, first argument should route name and a second argument you can pass array with list of parameters that you have defined in route file, with specific route to be used.

Let me know if you still need my help.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I've updated the routes and blade form link exactly as you describe but still get "Route [user_admin/settings.edit] not defined." Also, shouldn't the form action be action="{{route('settings', rather than {{route('profile'? Mind you, I tried both and both failed.

Comment: I think the 'id' is not needed because it should pull the id from sign up info. All I am trying to do is click a link in user dashboard which will direct user to 'settings.blade.php'. The issue is that I can't open the user dashboard because the link to the user_admin/settings.edit has an error

Comment: UPDATE: I think the issue is definitely with the form method POST. I've reworded my question and given full code in a new thread here so that it is clearer. Please take a look if you get chance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043675/form-method-post-action

Answer (score 0):

correct link was {{ route('settings.update') }}

The problem was caused due to a previous change to user name, we added user first_name and last_name to the sign up form, which meant that 'name' was not being recognised. After updating links to point to first_name and last_name, and adding above link, it all worked fine.